# Static Cells overlapping with UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a UITableViewController with static cells. When I have more than one row for a cell, they are overlapping each other. Auto Layout does not fix the issue. Here are screenshots of the Storyboard and the Simulator. I do not have any code for the class that I created for the UITableViewController, so that shouldn't be an issue.

**EDIT:** If I run the simulator with the empty cells, it shows up fine.

[image: Storyboard with UILabels and UITextField]

[image: Simulator]

[image: Simulator without UILabels and UITextField]

Comment: Could you provide your UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource codes.

Comment: I haven't written any code for this UITableViewController yet. By the way, I am using Xcode 6 Beta 4. Could be a bug with Xcode.

Comment: I had the same issue but finally managed to get it fixed with a bit of fiddling. I've just created another table view and I'm having the same issue but this time the screen is just blank. Weird.

Comment: think you should set the height of row in heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @kkocabiyik That worked. I was thinking about doing that but the tutorial that I was following is for Objective-C and it didn't require that. I know you have to write this method when you have a custom cell even with Xcode 5. I think this is a bug because if you set the heights in the Interface Builder, why should you have to do it in code again? If you want to write this in the answer, I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the height of row in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. It doesn't get the height of the row from Interface builder instead you need to set it programmatically otherwise it set the default value 44. In iOS8 there is another feature called self-sizing cells. Once you create the constraints between UI items it dynamically changes the height of the cell as you scroll down/up. See  [this](http://kemal.co/index.php/2014/07/an-example-of-self-sizing-cells-introduced-in-ios8/) i just wrote as a tutorial.

Comment: Tutorial link is broken kindly check it out